# Should reducer functions passed into useReducer() be declared outside my Component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm reading the docs for [`useReducer`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer) and noticed that all the examples declare the reducer function outside the body of the component, like this

```js
import { useReducer } from 'react';

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === 'incremented_age') {
    return {
      age: state.age + 1
    };
  }
  throw Error('Unknown action.');
}

export default function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { age: 42 });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'incremented_age' })
      }}>
        Increment age
      </button>
      <p>Hello! You are {state.age}.</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is there any substantive benefit to this or is it just a convention? In particular, I'm thinking about the stability of the function reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does improve performance slightly to define it just once.

First, by defining it outside, you no longer have to create the function on ever render. This very slightly speeds things up. But it is admittedly quite a tiny amount of speedup (nanoseconds).

Second and more important, useReducer has some internal optimizations which can allow it to do less work if the reducer does not change. When you dispatch an action to the reducer, react immediately computes the new state. It needs to do this so it can skip the render if the state hasn't changed. But it also saves the computed state. Later, when a render happens, if the reducer has not changed then it can used the saved state instead of computing it again.

So, if your reducer changes, then it must be run at least twice (more if concurrent rendering causes the render to abort). If it does not change, then it runs exactly once. The impact of this optimization will depend on how complex your reducer is.

See this code for where they implement this optimization: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L3223

Comment: This makes sense, but the thing that is throwing me is a snippet from the [old React docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) that states *React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.* Was this guarantee removed in React 18? Or perhaps the guarantee only exists if the reference to the reducer function does not change?

Comment: That guarantee is still true. The dispatch function returned by the hook will be a stable function reference. But when you call dispatch, dispatch will look up the current state and current reducer and operate on those.

Answer (score 0):

> Components with many state updates spread across many event handlers can get overwhelming. For these cases, you can consolidate all the state update logic `outside your component` in a single function, called a reducer.

If multiple components do some operation with the same state, declaring the reducer outside allows you to reuse it in all.

Keeping the reducer separate from the components will make your codebase easy to maintain.

Comment: Fair point, but what if my reducer function is clearly specific to one component? For the sake of readability, it'd be better to declare it next to the `useReducer` that uses it. Are there **any** drawbacks (particularly related to performance) in this situation?

Comment: If it's specific to one component, reducer will re-create at each render, but there is not any significant drawback. You should go with readability.